# Full-Screen Issues With Tomb Raider on PC

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

Every time I launch Tomb Raider, it launches in windowed mode. I have checked both full screen and exclusive fullscreen option. Resolution is 1366 x 768. What is causing this?

This is my configuration:

```
Windows 7 64 bit
6 GB RAM
Intel Core i5 2.3GHz
Geforce GT 525M
```

Comment: Windows modes??

Comment: @jeffreylin_ I believe he means "Tomb Raider is launching in windowed mode" and he wishes the game to launch in full screen mode instead.

Comment: @SimonL: Yes, I am sorry If I wasnt clear. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latest patch available on steam has fixed this problem.

The [changelog](http://store.steampowered.com/news/10113) says:

> - Addressed some stability and startup issues on machines that have both Intel and NVIDIA graphics hardware.
> - Fix for players being unable to progress related to the boat in the beach area.
> - Some fixes for crashes on startup and when selecting Options.
> - Some small improvements to TressFX hair rendering.
> - Fixes for various graphics glitches, including certain effects not being visible in fullscreen mode.
> - Fixed a problem that caused some users to not be able to use exclusive fullscreen.
> - Added support for separate mouse/gamepad inversion for aiming, as well as support for x-axis inversion.
> - Fixes related to the benchmark scene and benchmark mode.
> - Various other small fixes.

Answer (score 3):

Try unchecking the 'Exclusive Full Screen' option (leaving the 'full screen' option checked).  This worked for me on Win7 with an ATI Radeon 7800 series.

Comment: It worked! Win8 + GeForce 9800 GT. Thanks!